# ElasticSearch data modeling with Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, elasticsearch, full-text-search, search-engine

I'm studying Elastic search and trying to modeling with mysql tables.
I have Mysql tables below for example.

**Book Table**

- id
- title
- abstract
- publisher_id

ex) book table

---

### id | title | abstract | publisher_id

3 | book title A | A book about elastic search. | 12

---

**Authors Table**

- id
- name
- country
- book_id(id from Book table)

ex) authors table

---

### id | name | country | book_id

1 | Alex | Korea | 3

2 | John | USA | 3

---

author could be more than one person.

**Publisher Table**

- id
- name

ex) publisher table

---

### id | name

12  | Packt pub

---

**In my thoughts, i could convert like below for elastic search index.**

**Book index**

- id *int*
- title *string*
- abstract *string*
- authors *array* (id from Authors index. Authors could be more than one.)
- publisher *int* (id form publisher index)

**Authors index**

- id *int*
- name *string*
- country *string*

**Publisher index**

- id *int*
- name *string*

What i need to do is, search for Book title and abstract and get author's id.
And then show authors list.
For mysql, i would do like this.

```
Select * from authors where id in (select authors_id from book where match(title,abstract) against('${keyword}' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

How can i do this for elastic search?
Is there a better way to modeling?
and I also want to know how to query
*First search authors ids from book index and search with these ids from authors again??
or any other solution???*

Comment: first You should read some document about nosql database modeling. quick answer is you should put all data in one index. the query will be easier. you can AND in term or match query.

Comment: Hamid is right, get some good reads about document based noSql. When designing an index you need to do an paradigm change. Instead of thinking about the sorage first, think about the queries you need to perform on the data and optimise for the queries and somtimes you need to keep data redundant, what is absolutely fine here. Have fun!

Comment: @Sehun, I totally agree with hamid and ibexit and in this case you should just store all the data in same index, added a sample related small example in my answer to make it clear.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I thought wrong way.... Now i understand. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to achieve using a single index in Elasticsearch(ES) as pointed by other ES experts and I may not be able to give the proper ES query but my below example gives you idea, on how to model your data and query it.

**Index mapping**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "abstract":{
        "type" : "text"
      },
      "author" :{
        "type" : "text",
        "fielddata" : true // instead of this, you can use `keyword` field for better perf, this is just for ex
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index sample docs**

```
{
  "title" : "hello world",
  "abstract" : "hello world is common in computer programming",
  "author" : ["sehun, stackoverflow"]
}

{
  "title" : "foo bar",
  "abstract" : "foo bar is common in computer programming",
  "author" : ["opster, stackoverflow"]
}
```

**Search query to search on `title` and `abstract` and agg on author field**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "common",
      "fields": [
        "title",
        "abstract"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Cities": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "author"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search results**

```
hits": [
      {
        "_index": "internaledgepre",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "title": "foo bar",
          "abstract": "foo bar is common in computer programming",
          "author": [
            "opster, stackoverflow"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "internaledgepre",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "title": "hello world",
          "abstract": "hello world is common in computer programming",
          "author": [
            "sehun, stackoverflow"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "Cities": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "stackoverflow",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "opster",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "sehun",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your perfect answer. However, I think i cannot put all of data from MySQL. So is it okay to use both Elastic Search and MySQL? Finding the book from Elastic Search and find author information from MySQL.

Comment: @SehunPark, you can use mysql as source of truth but why to find author info from mysql and add another hop in the transaction

Answer (score 1):

NoSQL doesn’t support joins like SQL supports. So all data should be indexed in one document.

Do go through nosql datamodelling, architecture, significances and also learn how it’s different from SQL.